# Should the @spoverflowfeed Twitter account be turned off?

Tags: discussion

The [@spoverflowfeed](http://twitter.com/spoverflowfeed) Twitter account is still running back from Stack Exchange 1.0 days.

Is this something we should/can get turned off? [@StackSharePoint](http://twitter.com/StackSharePoint) is the official Twitter account for the site and has a much more intelligent tweeting algorithm.

Comment: Yeah @StackSharePoint is enough for me right now. We don't want to spam! :)

Comment: I've e-mailed @RobertCartaino to ask if this is OK and will report back when I know more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've turned off the feed and linked a tweet back to @StackSharePoint to hopefully grab anyone following that account but not the official one.  In a day or so I'll take care of the account itself.

Answer (score 2):

Yea, turn of the old one (I'm seeing double...). But don't close the account just yet - use it to make some announcements on the new site and new twitter account.

Comment: well name-wize i think @spoverflowfeed could come in handy **if** we go back to that name once out of beta

Comment: @AndersRask "Ask Ubuntu", "Seasoned Advice", "On Startups" all use Twitter accounts prefixed with **Stack** (see http://stackexchange.com/sites). Plus `@StackSharePoint` has twice the number of followers of `@SPOverflowFeed`. So doubt the SE team would keep that account anyway...

Comment: @Wictor Feature requests for this sort of thing have so far failed because Jeff of SE believes people tweeting about sites from their own accounts [is much more valuable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92235/would-allowing-moderators-to-update-their-stack-exchange-sites-twitter-accounts/100964#100964).